# Creating animation on scroll with self written easy script mostly by switch case

Tags: javascript, animation, switch-statement, css-animations

Well I am very new with javascript, have always loved to work on my own codes as it is easier to edit.
I am working on making a website which animates on scroll.

By seeing many tutorials I am able to make the div animation on a particular scroll from top

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("animate").className = "boxl1";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("animate").className = "";
    }
 if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("animate1").className = "boxl2";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("animate1").className = "";
    }
}
```

```css
#main{
 width:1000px; height:2000px; float:left; background-color:#000;
}

#left{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#F00;
}
.boxl1{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
 background-image:url(gif/1.png);
 transform:scaleX(-1);
 animation-name:lefty;
 animation-duration:5s;
}

@keyframes lefty{
 0%{
  margin:0px;
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
 
 100%{
  margin:400px;
  transform:rotate(270deg);
 }

 
}





#right{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#0F0;
}

.boxl2{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
    background-color:#FFF;
 background-image:url(gif/1.png);
 float:right;
 animation-name:travel;
 animation-duration:5s;
}

@keyframes travel{
 0%{
  margin:0px;
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
 
 100%{
  margin:400px;
  transform:rotate(360deg);
 }

 
}







#leftd{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#0F0;
}

#rightd{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#F00;
}
```

```html
 <div id="main">
 <div style="margin-top:400px;">
 
  <div id="left">
    
     <div id="animate"></div>
    
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    
     <div id="animate1"></div>
    
    </div>
    <div id="leftd">
    
     
    
    </div>
    <div id="rightd">
    
     
    
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Now all i want into this is that it should not complete the animation until i scroll down and reverse it when i scroll up.

the method i think is, i can create many boxes in css (like boxl1, boxl2,boxl3,...n) with different margins, and make a switch statement, but as i am too new to this, can you help me how does it works? I saw many tutorials they all show day and date, or names nothing for class and divs

Many answers here ask to get a js library and stuff, but i want to write it myself, if you can help, it would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a solution, but https://greensock.com/ would be plain fantastic in this case.